# Can I unpack/destructure a typing.NamedTuple?

Tags: python, namedtuple, argument-unpacking, destructure

This is a simple question so I'm surprised that I can't find it asked on SO (apologies if I've missed it), and it always pops into my mind as I contemplate a refactor to replace a tuple by a NamedTuple.

**Can I unpack a `typing.NamedTuple` as arguments or as a destructuring assignment, like I can with a `tuple`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** you certainly can.

```py
from typing import NamedTuple

class Test(NamedTuple):
    a: int
    b: int

t = Test(1, 2)

# destructuring assignment
a, b = t
# a = 1
# b = 2

def f(a, b):
    return f"{a}{b}"

# unpack
f(*t)
# '12'
```

Unpacking order is the order of the fields in the definition.

Comment: Upvoted because technically correct, but this seems prone to error.  I wish python supported object destructuring like JS:  `{ a, b } = t` where code can't break from misordering.

Comment: @BenJones I agree. I suppose a `NamedTuple` is still fundamentally a _tuple_, i.e. ordered, so only "makes sense" to use where order is meaningful. But in the real world it's perfect to as a lightweight immutable structure without a meaningful order on the entries, so it would be nice to able to be able to forget that order exists.